# Problem of semisimple rings

Tags: ring-theory

Someone can tell me which of the rings $\mathbb{Z}_n$ are semisimple?
I don't have any idea of how start to prove it.
Thank you in advance!

Comment: What definition of semisimple have you been given?

Comment: what happens when $n$ is square free?

Answer (score 1):

I know a simple fact about the semisimple modules i.e. $\text{Socl}(M)=M$:

> If $M$ is a left $R$ module, then the following statements are equivalent:
>
> 1. $M$ is semisimple.
> 2. Every submodule of $M$ is a direct summation in $M$.
> 3. $M$ is a direct sum of $\{S_i\}_{i\in I}$ of a family of simple sub modules.

I think 2 is one of useful hints here to get you an idea.

Comment: $\large +1^{+^+}\quad \ddot\smile$

Answer (score 1):

If n is divisible by $p^2$ for some prime p, then you can easily produce a nonzero element which squares to zero, showing the Jacobson radical is nonzero.

So, the semisimple rings would have to be among the n that are square free. To finish, apply the Chinese remainder theorem...